# Why standalone class reverses \parshape indentation (such that it appears on the end of each line, not the beginning) and how to change that?

Tags: paragraphs, standalone, parshape

You can replace `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}` with `\documentclass{article}` to see the difference. How do I make `\parshape` work as intended while using `standalone`?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \parshape 3 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm
  This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.
  This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4.
  This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.
  \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is not standalone but varwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the width already, just wrap it in a `\parbox` of that width.  In this circumstance the `varwidth` option can be omitted.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\parbox{40mm}{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \parshape 3 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm
  This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.
  This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4.
  This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.
  \par}
\end{document}
```

[image]